# MySQL C++ compilation fail

Tags: c++, mysql, compilation

I'm trying to make a C++ program with a connection to a MySQL database. I've downloaded the mySQL connector, and ( as it seems to be required, but I'm not quite sure what it is ) something called a boster library. Now as I compile, I get this: http://jensesserver.org/files/minggwmysqlfail.PNG

What I can figure out is that I need to link the booster library, can someone tell me how to do that?

Thanks in advance : )

And by the way, I'm using MinGW on Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

You are not (yet) trying/failing to *link* boost, you're trying and failing to include one of its header files. You need to include a `-I` option on the compilation line telling the compiler where to find the header(s) that it cannot locate.

If you don't have the boost package installed, you will need to take care of that first.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is is violating the comment guidelines, but now I have the include working. Now it just complains about som conflicts with uint_8 or something along the lines of that??
Is there an easy way to fix this, or am I on my way to an adventure of messing with flags and files?

Comment: Your comment isn't a violation but the question it asks doesn't have enough information to use to assist you with. I would suggest you start a new question and include the details of this new problem.

Comment: Right o', will do : ) Thanks for the replys